# How to Fit Line from Circle Center

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to do fit line from circle center like this picture and than I want to find intersect coordinates for circle like p7,p8,p3,p3,p1:
[image]

So I wrote this code

```
     vector<Moments> mu(contours.size() );
  for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
     { mu[i] = moments( contours[i] ,false); }

 vector<Point2f> mc( contours.size() );
  for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
     { mc[i] = Point2f( mu[i].m10/mu[i].m00 , mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00 ); }
      for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
      {
        cout<<" "<<mc[i]<<endl;
      //    circle( contourImage, mc[i], 4,Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ) , 1, 1, 0 );
    fitLine(mc);
    int lefty = (-lines[2]*lines[1]/lines[0])+lines[3];
    int righty = ((image.cols-lines[2])*lines[1]/lines[0])+lines[3];

    line(contourImage,mc[i],Point(309,165),Scalar(255,0,0),2);
  // line(contourImage,mc[i].x,m.c[i].y,Scalar(0,0,125),1,8,0);
   imshow("fitline",contourImage);
```

But I get this result:
[image]

After this I want to find p7 and p8 coordinates,p5 andp6 coordinates,p4 and p1 coordinates andp3 and p2 coordinates
In addition my function fitLine is here:

```
 vector<float> fitLine(vector<Point2f>  points){ 
    vector<float> line; 
    cv::fitLine(points,line,CV_DIST_L2,0,0.001,0.001); 
    return line; 
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: *"I want to do this"* - This is not nearly enough information to understand, what you are after. It's probably a good idea to take the [tour], since you haven't done so. Also recommended: [Ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was assumed that, u know the Radius and center. U have to draw 8 lines of the angle difference of (360/8) from center.

x2= center(x) + radius(x) + cos(theta);

y2 = center(y) + radius(y) + sin(theta);

theta = 3.14 *angle/180;
try this...